# Another "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

And yet another package-hell question...

I have an Azure Function v1 targeting net472 with a project dependency targeting netstandard2.0 or net472 or both.

When running the function, I get `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0` from this assembly.

This assembly has the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` in the bin folder if I set the target to net472, but not for netstandard2.0

The Azure Function does **not** have the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` in its bin folder.

deps.json has the following entry
[image: screenshot]

My mistake or how can I fix this corruption?

Actually I get similar effects with Newtonsoft.JSON, where either v10 or v12 cannot be loaded, depending on which one I install (the other version is always missing)

Comment: Is there an inconsistency in versions used and stored DLL's ? Perhaps?

Comment: The packages folder has v4.5.4

Comment: I don't see 4.5.4 above, perhaps make sure all those versions match what you already have?

Comment: Well yes, but 4.5.4 is installed everywhere :)
Can deps.json be modified somehow?

Comment: I would try hard to ge the versions to match, either by changing one or the other.

Comment: I gave up and went all the way. Huge amount of work but getting more promising results than pulling my hair with older and seemingly unsupported packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I gave up on Azure Functions v1 and moved the whole project to v3 using netstandard2.0. Things start to work again. Probably not a good place to be when mixing new and unsupported in-between projects.